# AWS Lambda deployment

Tags: powershell, deployment, aws-lambda, teamcity, aws-cli

I'm trying to deploy my lambdas (.NET Core 2.0) into AWS by using AWS CLI + TeamCity + Powershell script. I have some steps , including deploy step and applying new aliase number step. 
While deploy step I don't get alias number (lambda version). A script returns me something like "function = ", but it should be like "result = 44 (or any other lambda version)".

Here's a script (mix of Powershell + AWS CLI commands).

```
FOR ( /F "tokens=* delims=" %%%A IN ('dotnet lambda deploy-function MyLambda --profile default --region my-server-region --configuration Release --function-publish true') DO ( set result=%%%A )){
FOR ( /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims= " %%%A IN ('echo %%%result%%%') DO ( set result=%%%F )){

@echo on
echo %env.MyLambdaVersion%
@echo off
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.MyLambdaVersion' value='%%result%%']"
}
}
```

I actually don't know what I do wrong, actually this script was written before I started to work on this project. Any advice or any link will be helpfull, thanks :)

EDIT

I expect this kind of respinse, where i can get MyLambda version
[Succesfull build scrinshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/117Dg.jpg)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/117Dg.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOIGr.jpg

But instead of it I'm getting this result.
[Invalid response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/117Dg.jpg)

EDIT 2
Output of the script in text format

```
Step 17/36: Deploying new version of Lambda "MyLambda" (Command Line) (3m:16s)
[13:27:03][Step 17/36] Starting: C:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script1964828788270486366.cmd
[13:27:03][Step 17/36] in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\3f3a1ea85ff2ff09
[13:30:10][Step 17/36] 
[13:30:11][Step 17/36] C:\BuildAgent\work\3f3a1ea85ff2ff09\Proj\Lambda\Proj.Lambda.MyLambda>echo   
[13:30:12][Step 17/36] ECHO is on.
[13:30:16][Step 17/36] "
[13:30:16][Step 17/36] ##teamcity[setParameter name='env.MyLambdaVersion' value='function: ']
[13:30:16][Step 17/36] "
[13:30:20][Step 17/36] Process exited with code 0
```

Comment: Seems that's not a powershell but usual windows batch

Comment: Thank you , dagget, now it's much more easier to research exceptions)

Comment: Ok, I still don't understand why I don't get lambda version. I run script locally, but no result. Any advices?

Comment: your script just runs the command `dotnet lambda .....` and tries to parse some value from the result. please edit your question and add output example of this command and show which value you'd like to catch from output...

Comment: it's hard to debug your script if we don't know the real output of the command `dotnet lambda deploy-function MyLambda --profile default --region my-server-region --configuration Release --function-publish true`. keep in your build step just this command and show output in text format, and not as a screenshot.

Comment: Hello, daggett, sorry for delay, here's output of the command : in EDIT 2

Comment: The problem is solved. The reason of this error was in .NET Core version. AWS lambdas support only .NET Core 1.0 or 2.1+ , and I had .NET Core 2.0. I've just updated my .NET Core version in VS and in AWS, and TeamCity deployed it successfully